# Remote SSH command in Runtime exiting with code 255

Tags: java, java-7

```
String ipAddress = address.getHostAddress();
responseObject.put("ipAddress", ipAddress);
String loginCommand = COMMAND_SSH + userName + "@" + ipAddress;
Process remoteProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(loginCommand);
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(remoteProcess.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remoteProcess.getInputStream()));
//out.println(password);
while (in.ready()) {
    String s = in.readLine();
    LOGGER.info(s);
}
out.println(COMMAND_EXIT);
```

The above code when debugged always shows `remoteProcess` has exited with the code `255` and I cannot figure out why? I tried replacing the loginCommand with `ls` and it's working properly? May I know where I am going wrong.

P.S : I'm not allowed to use external libraries(including OS).

Comment: Consider either redirecting the error output to the standard output or also reading the error output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues but none of them have to be the exact cause of your issues as there is simply not enough code given.

```
while (in.ready()) {
    String s = in.readLine();
    LOGGER.info(s);
}
```

in.ready() returns true when the stream is ready. You are introducing a race condition here. If the while() is reached before the in-stream is ready it skips this entire statement.
Instead use:

```
String s;
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null){
    LOGGER.info(s);
}
```

Also, you might want to make sure that you also read the standard error output.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll definitely try this out and tell you how it went. Also this is the main part of the code, rest of it is just receiving the parameters

Comment: @MageshKumaar your code does not show how you are obtaining COMMAND_EXIT, also COMMAND_SSH is not shown ;)

Comment: Those are final strings whose values are `ssh ` and `exit`